# How do I get rid of prefixes from a csv using sed?

Tags: sed

Consider this sample csv file:

```
potato.cat,potato.dog
3,5
7,1
```

Using `sed`, I'm trying to get:

```
cat,dog
3,5
7,1
```

I've tried: `cat test.csv | sed '1 s/(\w+\.(\w+))\,?/$1\,/g'` and variants
thereof, but haven't quite been able to get it. I feel like this should be easy but I'm making a botch of it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `tail -n +2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ sed -E '1 s/[a-z]+\.//g' test.csv
cat,dog
3,5
7,1
```

No need to pipe `cat | sed`